# jQuery: OnClick change option 'selected' attribute

Tags: jquery, html

this would be my second post here, would be great if someone could support with his magic knowlegde :)

What I would like to achieve?

Changing the option I would like to remove attribute 'selected' from default and add to option I clicked.

This is my desired HTML:

```
<select class="flex-calc-length">
   <option value="6">1/2 year</option>
   <option value="12" selected>1 year</option>
   <option value="24">2 years</option>
   <option value="36">3 years</option>
   <option value="48">4 years</option>
   <option value="60">5 years</option>
</select>
```

But overall this is a part of materialize.css Select feature which adding a bunch of code, converting from above to:

```
<div class="select-wrapper flex-calc-length">
<span class="caret">▼</span>
<input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-3062497b-bc40-0e77-91c3-550f09e8e872" value="1 year">
<ul id="select-options-3062497b-bc40-0e77-91c3-550f09e8e872" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 215.2px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; opacity: 1;">
    <li class=""><span>1/2 year</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>1 year</span></li>
    <li class="active selected"><span>2 years</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>3 years</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>4 years</span></li>
    <li class=""><span>5 years</span></li>
</ul>
<select class="flex-calc-length initialized" data-select-id="3062497b-bc40-0e77-91c3-550f09e8e872">
    <option value="6">1/2 year</option>
    <option value="12" selected="">1 year</option>
    <option value="24">2 years</option>
    <option value="36">3 years</option>
    <option value="48">4 years</option>
    <option value="60">5 years</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't that happen by default ?

Comment: The browser will change the selected attribute automatically, no effort is required on your part.

Comment: This IS the default HTML behavior of a select.

Comment: Forgot to add, I am using this feature with materialize.css which is adding many lines of code to that. Somehow it's not changing by default.

Comment: How do you check the source code? View source, or with developer tools?

Comment: Developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you're trying to achieve?

```js
let prevVal = $('.flex-calc-length').val();
function replaceSelection() {
  selectedVal = $('.flex-calc-length').val();
  
  $('.flex-calc-length > option').each(function(i, item) {
    if(item.value === prevVal) {
      $(item).removeAttr("selected");
    }
  })
  
  $('.flex-calc-length > option').each(function(i, item) {
    if(item.value === selectedVal) {
      $(item).attr("selected", "true");
      prevVal = $(item).val();
    }
  })
}
```

```css
option[selected] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="flex-calc-length" onchange="replaceSelection()">
   <option value="6">1/2 year</option>
   <option value="12" selected>1 year</option>
   <option value="24">2 years</option>
   <option value="36">3 years</option>
   <option value="48">4 years</option>
   <option value="60">5 years</option>
</select>
```

If you need an explanation - just ask.

Comment: Many thanks for answer, this helped me to go further with whole idea.